# Make Windows backup image of secondary drive

Tags: windows, macrium

I recently upgraded from a SATA drive to a pcie drive (C: drive) and would like to create a disk image of the old SATA drive using Macrium Reflect Free.  I’ve plugged the SATA drive into a free SATA port and the computer and Macrium both recognize it (F: drive).

In Macrium, on the left side of the main screen, there is a list of Backup Tasks.  The first one is “Image selected disks on this computer” and the second is “Create an image of the partitions required to backup and restore Windows.”

If I select the second option, I can only make an image of the C: drive of my computer.

The only way I can make an image of the old SATA drive (F:) is by selecting the first option.

I got the impression from the Macrium knowledgebase, that the second option “Create an image of the partitions required to backup and restore Windows” copies hidden files required for successfully restoring Windows.

Does anyone know if the option to “Image selected disks on this computer” will work for restoring Windows?  Or will I have to remove the pcie drive from my system and boot into the old SATA drive to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

The best way for me to do this kind of stuff is to **boot from a Linux-live usb-drive** and use **gparted** to make the disk image of the sata drive (or any drive you want). gparted is installed by default in the Mint distribution live disk.

I never used the Macrium software so no idea how it works but the Linux way has been very efficient for me in the past to copy, backup or change any partitions without Windows messing up things like your bootloader or anything essential to boot your new installation.

my personal favourite is:
[Linux Mint Cinnamon](https://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=284)
but you can use any linux distribution you want, it's fast, easy and safe because you boot from a **usb disk**.